# shell and regex matching spaces

Tags: regex, shell, lex

Here's my question:

e.g

```
echo 123\<  abc\\\ efg
```

The output should be

```
123< abc\ efg
```

My regex in lex file is

```
[^\n ]*[\\]+[^\n]
```

If I use this regex, my output is going to be

```
 123< abc\  efg
```

which is wrong.
Can anybody tell me how to match \(space) and regular (space) respectively?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `echo 123\<  abc\\\ efg` and `echo "123\<  abc\\\ efg"`; in the first `bash` has a chance to process the escaped characters in the string before displaying them. So the question is, how are you calling your lexer in order to produce `123< abc\  efg`?

Comment: I redirected 123\< abc\\\ efg into a file, thus bash would not process the backslash. Anyway, that's not the point. If I use my regex to match the string, \(space) and regular space is the same. I don't know how to write the regex to match the two situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are looking for is a flex regular expression which will match a single shell token which does not contain quotes or other such complications.

Note that the characters which automatically terminate tokens are the following: `();<>&|` and whitespace. (The `bash` manual says `space` and `tab`, but I'm pretty sure that `newline` also separate words.)

Such a regular expression is possible, but (imho) it is of little use, partly because it doesn't take quoting (or bracketing: `a$(echo foo)b` is a single word), and partly because the resulting word needs to be rescanned for escape characters. But whatever. Here's a sample flex regex:

```
([^();<>&|\\[:space:]]|\\(.|\n))+
```

That matches any number of consecutive instances of:

- anything other than a metacharacter or an escape character, or
- an escape character followed by any single character, or
- an escape character followed by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct. When you type at the prompt

```
echo 123\<  abc\\\ efg
```

the following happens:

1. `bash` replaces `\<` with `<` (without the backslash, `bash` would treat `<` as in input redirection operator.
2. `bash` replaces `\\` with a single literal `\`
3. `bash` replaces '\ ` with a single literal space.
4. `bash` calls the `echo` command, passing it 2 arguments: `123<` and `abc\ efg`.
5. `echo` produces the output `123< abc\ efg`, a single string with a single space separating its two arguments.

Based on your regular expression, it looks like the string output in my step 5 above is what is stored in your file. From those 13 bytes, it would find 3 valid tokens: `123<`, `abc\`, and `efg`. If it prints them to standard output as a single string with a space separating each token, you would see `123< abc\  efg`. (There should be two spaces following that backslash; I can't seem to get multiple spaces to display.)

Comment: Yes.  The lexer will separate 123\< abc\\\ efg to three tokens which are 123<, abc\ , and efg. I don't know how to do to let lexer separate string like this to two tokens 123< and abc\ efg. Do you know how to deal with this?